# call argparse print_help from function

Tags: python

i would like to call argparse print_help() from inside a function, but parser is in another function. Let's say:

```
import argparse

def f():
    parser.print_help()

def a():
    f()


def _read_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="my description")
    parser.add_argument('-c', action='store_true')
    return parser


def main():
    parser = _read_args()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    a()



# MAIN

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

i thought 2 solutions:

1. make parser global
2. read args in main ( not main() )

the 1 i don't really like global variables, if possible i prefer not use it

the 2 present problems if importing the module

which is the best way to achieve this?

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to a variable inside a function, pass it as an argument.

```
def f(parser):
    parser.print_help()

def a(parser):
    f(parser)

...

def main():
    parser = _read_args()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    a(parser)
```

Comment: yes i know, but this is not the case, i don't want to pass the argument through the all the functions, because (in my mind) print_help should be accessible everywhere to call it when an error happens

Comment: If you want it to be accessible everywhere, then that's called a global variable. You've said you don't want to use one of those. Those are your two options for communicating data: As a parameter or as a global variable.